# Words for "Biased Arguments" in Latin

Tags: vocabulary

Is there such an expression in Latin that describes the following situations:

- Someone using arguments based on fear, patriotism and race/nationalism instead of logic for the purpose of trying to convince people quickly? For example: "If we don't pass this bill, everyone in our country will die!"
- Someone who can't reply to an argument and instead uses their authority to debunk the argument? For example: "I finished my work, can I leave early today?" . "No". "Why?" . "Because I am your boss and I said no".

Do such terms to describe these situations exist in Latin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example isn't quite right in a strictly logical sense. What if, for example, the passage of the bill prevented nuclear holocaust? But ignoring some extreme examples, this is probably best seen as an [appeal to emotion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_emotion), the Latin of which is ***argumentum ad passiones***.

The second example you give isn't a biased argument, because it's not an argument at all. It's not even an attempt to argue; it's simply a denial. For that particular scenario, you could use ***negatio***, which is a Latin word for "denial." I'd avoid *recusatio*, another word for "denial," since it carries additional connotations and is the term given for a particular rhetorical device.

An actual appeal to the authority (***argumentum ab auctoritate***) would be more along the lines of:

> It's not good to leave early even though you're finished because I'm the boss and I know best.

In the above example, the correctness of the argument is due to its appeal to the authority of claimant. It's making a logical statement, and to put it into syllogistic terms:

P1 I'm the boss
P2 I know best
P3 I say it's not good to leave early
C It's not good to leave early

The fallacy is clearer there.